# Process communication through file in bash

Tags: bash, interprocess

I am doing bash scripting and want to set up communication between two processes using write to file. The walkthrough of the program will be:

1. Process 1 opens file "file.txt" and writes some input specified by user in terminal
2. Process 2 opens same file from other end and constantly reads it for update.
3. If process 2 finds an update, it displays the output to the user.

Currently I am stuck at determining when the file has been updated and to store the updated part of the file (in this case the last line) in a variable.

Any help will be appreciated!

P.S. assume both process scripts are in the same location and are being run on different terminals.

*Update*

As some have suggested using named pipes with textfile being the pipe. I am running the processes on a cluster sharing the filesystem and the processes can be on any two nodes. So commands sent by process 1 is written to the file and is read by process 2 on a different node. Named pipes, on the other hand, requires both processes to be stored locally.

Comment: Why don't you use a named pipe instead of a plain file?

Comment: Can you use an unnamed pipe? `proc1 | proc2` ?

Comment: Named pipes only work if both the processes are on the same machine. I am running the code on a cluster where nodes can be anywhere. Named pipes doesn't really work then.

Comment: Have `Process 2` run a `tail -f` on the file and then grep the output of that, with `--line-buffered`, or read it with `awk` and use `system()` to do something with the stuff it finds.

Comment: @MarkSetchell some code might help to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the following code:

Process 2 reading the file for updates:

```
filename="testfile.txt"
tail -n 0 -F $filename | \
while read LINE
do
echo "$LINE"
done
```

Process 1 writes to the file using simple `>>`

The `tail` command is what solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

as alluded to above, probably the easiest way is to create a named pipe, e.g.,

```
mkfifo file.txt
```

see, e.g., this short [tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash)

In loose terms, having created the pipe, the first process writes to it as if it were a "normal" file. Any reads performed by the second process then block until there is a new "content" available.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to pipes. Upvote for attaching tutorial along with. However, I would like to reuse this file and read contents of data written later. It seems that even after I close the processes, I am unable to read the file I cannot open it in any text editor.

Comment: the pipe does not store data per se, it works merely as a "communication channel", either you can create a copy of the data in one of the processes for later use or you can use some kind of synchronization techniques such as `lockfile` and friends - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-unix-commands-can-be-used-as-a-semaphore-lock?lq=1

Comment: I tried pipes and it doesn't really fulfill my needs. Please see the update on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

**process1**

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    seq 1 100 >> sharedFile.txt
    sleep 3
done
```

**process2**

```
tail -f sharedFile.txt | awk '/^53/{print "Saw 53"}'
```

or if `process2` needs to run some command when it sees something:

```
tail -f sharedFile.txt | awk '/^53/{system("beep")}'
```

Comment: That works well! I wanted to echo the updated line to terminal on the other process. See my answer for the code I ended up writing.